# Databinding Winforms Textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

In a nutshell, this databinding works correctly

```
tbTotalTaxDue.DataBindings.Add("Text", I, "TotalTaxDue");
```

Namely, when I enter an invalid value—like an empty string—then tab out of the TB, the value therein just reverts to the previous value.  This makes sense since the value entered won't go into the object property of type decimal.  Unfortunately though, either of these  databindings:

```
tbTotalTaxDue.DataBindings.Add("Text", I, "TotalTaxDue", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, 0, "C");
tbTotalTaxDue.DataBindings.Add("Text", I, "TotalTaxDue", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, 0, "C");
```

Behave differently in that when the user enters an empty string, the input **will not** let the user tab out of the Text Box.  Is there any way to get the databinding to display as a currency, but simply cancel any invalid edits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple options:

1. Subclass `TextBox` and override the `OnValidating` event. If `Text` is empty, exit before  calling `MyBase.OnValidating()` to suppress the event.
2. Set `CausesValidation = False` on the `TextBox`, and handle the `TextChanged` event. If `Text` is not empty, manually validate it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It helps a great deal.  For my own edification, do you know why this is not necessary with the first validation?  The one without the custom display format?

Comment: The fourth argument to `Add()` is a boolean that enables formatting; you have it set to true in the second two calls. The default value for `Binding.FormattingEnabled` is false, and when set to true, it will perform type checking. Because an empty string cannot be cast to a decimal value, it does not validate.

Comment: Choice two breaks the formatting of the binding, but choice 1 works perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: I should have been more specific; *"manually validating"* in the second option should include calling `OnFormat()` on the correct `Binding` for the control. :)